# Make the parent div as big as its child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got some div in a parent div. The parent div should only be as big as its child divs.

So this is the current view

```js
function record(id, title, description, content, dateOfCreation) { // the object
  this.id = id;
  this.title = title;
  this.description = description;
  this.content = content;
  this.dateOfCreation = dateOfCreation;
  this.lastEdited = dateOfCreation;
}

function init(){
  var elements = []; // all records get stored here

  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) { // create some objects
    elements.push(new record(
         i,
         "title " + i,
         "description " + i,
         "content " + i,
         "date " + i));
  }

  $(elements).each(function (index, currentRecord) { // create the div containers
    var recordContainer = $("<div></div>");
    recordContainer.addClass("recordContainer");
    $(document.body).append(recordContainer);

    recordContainer.append($("<div>" + currentRecord.title + "</div>"));

    recordContainer.append($("<div>" + currentRecord.description + "</div>"));

    recordContainer.append($("<div>" + currentRecord.dateOfCreation + "</div>"));

    recordContainer.append($("<div>" + currentRecord.lastEdited + "</div>"));
  });
}

init(); // call the routine
```

```css
.recordContainer{
    margin: 10px;
    border: solid;  
    border-width: 1px;  
    border-radius: 2px;  
    border-color: #e8e9e9;
    box-shadow:  1px 1px 1px #999999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

So I want `recordContainer` having a relative size. When looking for some information, I tried out adding `display: inline;` to "recordContainer". But then doing this, the container gets weird (?). You need to try it out, then you will see what I mean.

How can I achieve my desired div?

Comment: the child container shouldn't be bigger than it's parent..

Comment: Have you tried: `.recordContainer {
    display: inline-block;
}`

Comment: oh, `display: inline-block;` that's it

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the parent div should automatically adopt the dimensions of the child div. For example, an empty div is 0x0 and only expands when you put stuff inside it.

Comment: @yoursweater Only if it's an inline element, block elements will always occupy full available width. Give me my sweater back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need them to be narrow but remain stacked vertically, use `display: table`, see the snippet below.

If you need them to be narrow and go onto the same line (and possibly wrap if that no longer fits), use `display: inline-block`.

```js
function record(id, title, description, content, dateOfCreation) {
  this.id = id;
  this.title = title;
  this.description = description;
  this.content = content;
  this.dateOfCreation = dateOfCreation;
  this.lastEdited = dateOfCreation;
}

function init() {
  var elements = []; // all records get stored here

  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) { // create some objects
    elements.push(new record(i, "title " + i, "description " + i, "content " + i, "date " + i));
  }

  $(elements).each(function(index, currentRecord) {
    var recordContainer = $("<div></div>");
    recordContainer.addClass("recordContainer");
    $(document.body).append(recordContainer);

    recordContainer.append($("<div>" + currentRecord.title + "</div>"));
    recordContainer.append($("<div>" + currentRecord.description + "</div>"));
    recordContainer.append($("<div>" + currentRecord.dateOfCreation + "</div>"));
    recordContainer.append($("<div>" + currentRecord.lastEdited + "</div>"));
  });
}

init(); // call the routine
```

```css
.recordContainer {
  margin: 10px;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border-color: #e8e9e9;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #999999;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I made some changes to improve semantics and performance as well. The problem is that the element "DIV" is by default a block element and therefore occupy the entire horizontal space.

I hope this solution helps you.

```js
function record(id, title, description, content, dateOfCreation) { // the object
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.content = content;
        this.dateOfCreation = dateOfCreation;
        this.lastEdited = dateOfCreation;
}

function init(){
var elements = []; // all records get stored here

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) { // create some objects
            elements.push(new record(
                 i,
                "title " + i,
                "description " + i,
                "content " + i,
                "date " + i));
}

$(elements).each(function (index, currentRecord) { // create the div containers
            var recordContainer = $("<div class='recordContainer'><div class='container container-" + index + "'></div></div>");
            $(document.body).append(recordContainer);

            $(".container-" + index).append("<div>" +
              "<p>" + currentRecord.title + "</p>" +
              "<p>" + currentRecord.description + "</p>" +
              "<p>" + currentRecord.dateOfCreation + "</p>" +
              "<p>" + currentRecord.lastEdited + "</p></div>");
        });
}

init(); // call the routine
```

```css
.recordContainer{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}

.container{
  margin: 0 .5em;
  padding: .5em;
  
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;  
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;  
  border-radius: 2px;  

  -webkit-box-shadow:  1px 1px 10px #ccc;
  -moz-box-shadow:  1px 1px 10px #ccc;
  box-shadow:  1px 1px 10px #ccc;
}

.container p {
  text-align: center;
}

.container p:nth-child(odd){
  background: #eee;
  margin: 0;
  padding: .3em .5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```